# Remove last element from an array without using pop()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript. I want to remove last element from an array, without using pop method. I've tried using length property, but I'm getting undefined in my console. Please help!

```
function lastElement(array) {

   return array[array.length-1];

}

lastElement([3,4,5,6]);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `slice()`

```
function lastElement(array) {
   return array.slice(0,array.length-1);
}

lastElement(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! Slice is a better option

Comment: `slice` does not change the array nor the length of the array. it does not remove an item.

Comment: @NinaScholz i know, but since it returns new array you can assign it. Thanks for your point. And I think author did not ask the question in right way

Comment: an assignment inside of the function does not change the array of the call (outside), because ot loses the object reference. you may try it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I meant not in function. To be more clear `arr = lastElement(arr)`

Comment: `lastElement` should return an element, not the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz But anyways I understand your point, if you go by the question my answer is incorrect

Comment: And what else should one go by, if not the question? ... which makes this answer incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the element first and then decrement the array length.

BTW, the handed over parameters are not an array. You need an array for this task, because if you take only arguments, the length change makes no sense.

```js
function lastElement(array) {
    var temp = array[array.length - 1];
    array.length = Math.max(0, array.length - 1); // prevent assigning negative values
    return temp;
}

var array = [3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(lastElement(array));
console.log(lastElement(array));
console.log(lastElement(array));
console.log(lastElement(array));
console.log(lastElement(array));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works